# Find next Date/Time in JPA query

Tags: java, jpa

I need to return the next meeting for a user. For example, to userId 1, the next meeting will be today (MeetingId 1), because today is 02-12-2019 13:12PM. If I search for the next meeting today at 15:00PM,  the next meeting will be at 09-12-2019 (MeetingiD 2). If I search for the next meeting tomorrow, the next meeting will be at 09-12-2019 (MeetingiD 2).

[image]

I'm using MYSQL database and the query (but I don't know how to search exactly):

```
@Query(select m from meeting m inner join m.group g inner join g.user u where u.id = :userId order by m.meetingDate desc)
Meeting getNextMeeting(@Param(userId) long userId)


public class Meeting {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @OneToMany()
    private Group group;
    private Date meetingDate;
    private Time meeting;
}

public class Group {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId",nullable = false)
    private User user;
}

public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
}
```

Comment: Then what's the problem ?

Comment: What database you are using?

Comment: If you are using postgres,  you can add this condition `and (date m.date + time m.time) > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and limit 1`

Comment: Sorry I updated my answer, but i'm using MYSQL database. And my problem is that I don't know how to search in a JPA query

Answer (score 0):

To get only one next meeting, You need to filter out all the future event using the below condition and limit 1.

Below query works, if you are using Postgres

`(date m.date + time m.time) > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and limit 1`

Answer (score 0):

Mysql has `now()` function that returns current date. 
Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_now.asp

Try this query:

```
@Query("select m from meeting m inner join m.group g inner join g.user u where u.id = :userId and m.meetingDate > now() order by m.meetingDate asc")
List<Meeting> getNextMeetings(@Param(userId) long userId)
```

You sorting should be ascending(from the closest date to now to the farthest). Query will return list of entities. I would suggest you to check the order in result query and take the first entity from the list -> list.get(0). Otherwise, you can sort it by yourself and take the first.